# Next 13 Fetch Failed

Tags: javascript, c#, next.js, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch from my .NET Core 7 API, but I am getting the following error:
*Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: fetch failed

Call Stack
Object.fetch
node:internal/deps/undici/undici (11413:11)
process.processTicksAndRejections
node:internal/process/task_queues (95:5)*

This is my code:

```
import Image from 'next/image'

async function getChamps () {
  const res = await fetch('https://localhost:7046/api/Champion')

  if (!res.ok) { // ! Recommended to handle errors
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }

  return res.json() // ? return the data
}

export default async function ListOfChampions () {
  const champions = await getChamps()

  return (
    <ul>
      {champions.map(champ => (
        <li key={champ.champion_id}>
          <Image src={champ.image} alt={champ.name} />
          <p>{champ.name}</p>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

If I make the GET request to https://localhost:7046/api/Champion with POSTMAN or just accessing to the browser, it works. But I cannot fetch it.

Any help?

Already tried to configure CORS in my API, but it does not work.

Comment: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/44062 For anyone having the same issue, this is the fix that I found.

Answer (score 0):

try changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 , i had a similar error but with strapi as a backend and solved it that way .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because your address is not working Restart the local server

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35686881)